# How to stargaze logistf regressions?

Tags: r, stargazer

I am using `logistf()` function for a Firth’s Logistic Regression with the `logistf` package. How do I stargaze the result? I used `stargazer(result)`, where result is the regression result, and I get `% Error: Unrecognized object type.`

Comment: See from the vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf a list of supported models. As the message saysm logistf package is not supported.

Comment: The usual caveat: don’t use ‘stargazer’ because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious package](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/comment/dkgw9q1/). Use ‘[modelsummary](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/)’ or ‘[texreg](https://github.com/leifeld/texreg/)’ instead, or literally anything else.